# Understanding Radon Nikodym proof in the book Measure Theory from Donald L.Cohn

Tags: integration, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

I'm reading the book Measure Theory (second edition) from Donald L.Cohn and
have a problem in understanding his proof of the $\sigma$-finite case of his
proof of the Radon-Nikodym theorem. In the book he first proves the case for
finite measures $\mu$, $\nu$ and then proceed to prove it for $\mu$ and $\nu$
as $\sigma$-finite measures on the measurable space $\langle X, \mathcal{A}
\rangle$. For this he considers a disjoint sequence $\{ B_n \}_{n \in
\mathbb{N}_0}$ of measurable sets such that $\mu (B_n)$ and $\nu (B_n)$ are
finite. So far I can follow the proof, however then he proceeds to use the
finite case to find a $g_n : X \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that $\nu (A) =
\int_A g_n d \mu$ for every measurable subset of $B_n$ and it is this which is
not clear to me. If you want to apply the finite case you must have a
measurable space with finite measures on it. So I thought of using the
measurable space $\langle B_n, \mathcal{A}_n \rangle$ where $\mathcal{A}_n$={$B_n \bigcap A : A \in \mathcal{A}$} and instead of $\mu, \nu$ using the measures $\mu_n$, $\nu_n$ (the restrictions of $\mu, \nu$  to $\mathcal{A}_n$). Using the finite case we have
then the existence of a measurable function $g_n : X \rightarrow [0, \infty)$
so that $\nu  (A) = \nu_n (A) = \int_A g_n d \mu_n$. Is this the correct way
to proceed and if so how would I prove that $\int_A g_n d \mu_n = \int_A g_n d
\mu$ and find a $g : X \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ such that $\int_A g
d \mu = \nu (A)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $n$, let
$\mu_n(E)=\mu\left(E \cap B_n\right) \quad$ and $\quad \nu_n(E)=\nu\left(E \cap B_n\right) \quad$ for any $E \in \mathcal{M}$

Then $\mu_n$ and $\nu_n$ are finite measures. Moreover, since $\nu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu, \nu_n$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu_n$.
Hence for each positive integer $n$, there is a non-negative measurable function $f_n$ on $X$ such that
$$
\nu_n(E)=\int_E f_n d \mu_n \quad \text { for all } E \in \mathcal{A}
$$

Note that $\mu_n(E)=\mu\left(E \cap A_n\right)=\int_E \chi_{B_n} d \mu$. so
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nu(E) & =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \nu_n(E)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_E f_n d \mu_n \\
& =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_E f_n \chi_{B_n} d \mu=\int_E \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n \chi_{A_n} d \mu
\end{aligned}
$$

Define $f=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n \chi_{B_n}$. Then $f$ has the desired property.
Hence the proof.

I would like to remark why $\int_E f_n d \mu_n  =\int_E f_n \chi_{B_n} d \mu$

Suppose $f$ is a simple function, then it is easy to check. Now suppose $f$ is non-negative function, one way to define the integral of it is through the MCT.
$\int_E f d \mu_n  =\lim_{i}\int_E f_i d \mu_n=\lim_{i}\int_E f_i \chi_{B_n} d \mu=\int_E f \chi_{B_n} d \mu$. That is enough for our proof since we have $f_n \geq 0$

Answer (score 2):

I think Cohn's $g_n$ is the same as yours. It is defined (and measurable) on $B_n$ by: for every measurable $A\subset B_n,$ $\nu(A)=\int_Ag_nd\mu.$

Next, simply define $g$ on $X$ by: its restriction to $B_n$ is $g_n.$ Since the $B_n$'s are disjoint (and there union is $X,$ which you forgot to mention), there is no problem.

Edit1: I just looked online at Cohn's book p.124 and this is exactly what he does(!).

Edit2: Note that your $\mathcal A_n$ is simply the set of measurable subsets of $B_n,$ and your $\mu_n,\nu_n$ are the restrictions of $\mu,\nu$ to it, so that for any measurable function $g$ and any $A\in\mathcal A_n,$ $\int_A gd\mu_n=\int_Agd\mu.$

Comment: I agree that $\forall C \in \mathcal{A}_n$ $\mu_n (C) = \mu (C)$ and $\nu_n
(C) = \nu$ but the problem is that I'm not convinced, using the definitions of
the measure integral, that the integrals are the same. I see a way of proving
this in general by starting with simple functions (where it is clearly true,
because we use the measure directly in the definition) and then proceed to non
negative measurable functions up to integrable functions. I had hoped for a
shortcut.

Comment: [Change of variables formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure#Main_property:_change-of-variables_formula) applied to the inclusion map $B_n\hookrightarrow X.$